# Using Excel interop to retrieve information from the range that meet criteria

Tags: c#, excel, com

```
oSheet = (Excel._Worksheet)xlWorkBook.ActiveSheet;   
oRng = oSheet.get_Range("T10", "T343");
```

The range `oRng` contains values of type double.  Each cell in Column `T` shows the max number of the associated row. How can i find out how many 1’s , 2’s 3’s ….. till 10 are in that range. Secondly Eg  if there are 20 rows with value =3 , I need to copy column `A`,`B`,`C` from those rows and store them for later use .i need  the count of the number of rows for each value from 1 to 10

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few general observations that might be enough to get you going:

Excel.Range has an AutoFilter method that you might be able to employ successively for each value that you're interested in (i.e, 1 through 10). Once you have the individual ranges returned by AutoFilter, you can them query them for the specific information you're interested in. See [C# Excel Automation: Retrieving rows after AutoFilter() with SpecialCells() does not seem to work properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742106/c-sharp-excel-automation-retrieving-rows-after-autofilter-with-specialcells) for issues associated with this approach.

Alternatively, you might be able to do something like create a simple dictionary that you could then populate as you iterate over column T.  For example, the dictionary could be of type Dictionary>.

As you proceed through column T, you encounter a value in each cell. If the cell value hasn't been seen before, you add it as a new key to the Dictionary.  For the associated value in the dictionary's key/value pair, you create a new List with the corresponding row number as its first element.

If the cell value has been seen before, you look it up in the dictionary, then add the corresponding row to the List associated with that key.

At the end of the day, your dictionary's keys contains all the values found in column T.  The number of rows associated with each value is just the number of elements in the associated List. With the row values in the List, you can then find "A[row value]", "B[row value]" and "C[row value]".