# C# Filter excel columns on more than one value

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, export-to-excel

I am exporting a data table to an excel in my windows form based application using C#.  The FilterList has the below values

```
string[] FilterList = new string[] {"Red", "Blue"};
```

But I only get the values filtered by "Blue". Below is the partial code where I am applying filter on one of my column.The column I am trying to filter has 7 different values in it from which I want to select only 2.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application app = new
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();   
        app.Visible = false;

        Workbook wb = app.Workbooks.Add(XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);   
        Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)wb.ActiveSheet;

       // Some business logic to fill the excel.............

        Range firstRow = (Excel.Range)ws.Rows[1];
        firstRow.Activate();
        firstRow.Select();
        firstRow.AutoFilter(5, FilterList.Count > 0 ? FilterList :
        Type.Missing,Excel.XlAutoFilterOperator.xlAnd, Type.Missing, true);
```

What am I doing wrongly here, Any help

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742106/c-sharp-excel-automation-retrieving-rows-after-autofilter-with-specialcells help?

Comment: Thanks for the link. It doesn't help me :(

Comment: Are you sure you can pass an array into the second parameter of the AutoFilter method? I wonder if this is looking for a single criteria? I'm not sure of the syntax required, but what if you passed in something like "Red||Blue" instead? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.autofilter.aspx.

Comment: @Richard the below answer which I posted worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok here you go:

The 3rd parameter of Autofilter method of Range accepts XlAutoFilterOperator, I changed it to `xlFilterValues` instead of `xlAnd` as I am using a single criteria object but having multiple criteria. Below is the code change I have done to have the filter select 2 values.

```
Range.AutoFilter(5, FilterList.Count > 0 ? FilterList.ToArray() : Type.Missing,
Excel.XlAutoFilterOperator.xlFilterValues, Type.Missing, true);
```

Source : [SocialMSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/45d43ed9-cbfd-4843-a8d6-2918705ec992/)

Hope it helps other SO users.

Comment: This was surprisingly hard to find.  Thank you for posting the answer.  I actually did this in a very similar fashion, but I used a `List` instead of an `Array`.  I used: `List<string> filterCriteria = new List<string>();`, then I populated the list with its own filter, then applied that to the Excel file.

Comment: Hi! What if it is an integer array? I mean I want a criteria where the numbers in the column should be greater or equal to one of the numbers in the array. I tried something like this with no luck: `Range.AutoFilter(5, FilterList.Count > 0 ? ">=" + FilterList.ToArray() : Type.Missing,
Excel.XlAutoFilterOperator.xlFilterValues, Type.Missing, true);`